# Navigation drawer items list

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I looked through the Android development documentation and couldn't find an answer to my question.

Is it possible to add an extra start space in the second category of items (Communicate) as shown in the right side picture?

[image]

Below is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_import"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="@string/menu_import" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="@string/menu_gallery" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="@string/menu_slideshow" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_tools"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="@string/menu_tools" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="@string/communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="@string/menu_share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="@string/menu_send" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the app:itemHorizontalPadding to change the padding before the icon and set padding as you want to add :

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationViewapp:itemHorizontalPadding="0dp"/>
```

You can also use a custom style:

```
<style name="CustomNavigationView" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.NavigationView">
   <item name="itemIconPadding">@dimen/.....</item>
   <item name="itemHorizontalPadding">@dimen/....</item>
   <item name="itemShapeInsetStart">@dimen/..../<item>
```

Comment: I tried to follow your suggestions and couldn't get it to work. Original menu code is attached above to original post. Not sure how to het it work...

Comment: @TopaZ We have tried debugging using your code but we suggest please create a custom menu. Please refer the following link.
https://johncodeos.com/how-to-create-a-custom-navigation-drawer-in-android-using-kotlin/

Comment: The above code works, but the padding works for all items in the Drawer. I like to see the extra margin just for the second category items.is that a possibility.

Comment: @TopaZ Yes, we already provided you with the solution in the previous comment, you need to create a custom drawer layout and add a margin in the second section, this is the only solution which fulfils your requirement.